# Can't get code for clicking a button in android programming to work

Tags: android, button

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public void calculate(View view){
    RadioButton Radio1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Radio1);
    RadioButton Radio2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Radio2);
    EditText input1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input1);
    EditText input2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input2);
    EditText input3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input3);
    TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
    Integer input11 = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText().toString());
    Integer input12 = Integer.parseInt(input2.getText().toString());
    Integer input13 = Integer.parseInt(input3.getText().toString());
    Integer e = ((input12*(6/10))*((514/100)/input11));

    Integer ans;

    if(Radio1.isChecked()){
        ans = (e*(73/100)-((15/1000)*input13));
    }
    else{
        ans = (e*(66/100)-((15/1000)*input13));
    }

    answer.setText(ans.toString());
}
}       
}
```

and I added this line to the button in android:

```
android:onClick="calculate"
```

I've searched online many places and they all did pretty much the exact same thing I did. (and i have hit ctrl+shift+o to import all) Please help me figure out why the line:

```
   public void calculate(View view){
```

is telling me void is an invalid type for the variable calculate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two extra `}` at the end. Remove them and it should work fine.

Comment: wow.. this wasn't exactly the answer, but one of those } was supposed to go after the onCreate method and it was causing the calculate method to have an error... and I had 1 extra at the end after that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        calculate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your clickListener in your java code!

```
 View v = findViewById(R.id.yourId);
 v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 void onClick(View v) {
 // your calculate function
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float or double. 6/10 is decimal format.

Comment: I know I found out later i can just change all of them to doubles. I'm still fairly new to android and wasn't really sure how it handled the doubles.